# Android Studios Adb server problems

Tags: adb, java

[image: when i try to start adb server manually in cmd in wind 7 64 bits]
I formatted the desktop and i'm try to install the Android Studios version 3.2.1 installation setup was completed but when try to run the project .It show error log like this Unable to detect adb version, adb output:I try to install the SDK manager manually. i try to update the tool with stable latest version 3.3.2 when run this project again show like this . So kindly help out from this issuse

Answer (score 0):

Hardly It takes 2 days to find the answer and fixed.

**Error Reasons happened  for me**

**OS some .dll files missing*

*Os get erupted**

I faced this type of error in my PC .So check and download the images file properly and install it.

Now i currently working on the Android studios for the project. I do no the exact reason for the error . But tired this way to Solve this error .

If you want to install the Android studios you have to check  the **Android Debug-Bridge** is running or not .

It has two methods

**Method 1:**

ABD is part of the Android SDK and is made up of three components: **a client, a daemon, and a server.**  Daemon is the server establishing the bridge for Emulator and USB type .
You have to download the Latest SDK manager from the **developer.android.com** in that there is a folder called **platform-tools** go inside the folder and see the **adb.exe file.**
Now open the Command prompt and make the directory where the SDk manager you download.

**Example** refer the screenshot below

D:cd sdk-tools-windows-4333796\platform-tools(this example)

then u see like this

D:\sdk-tools-windows-4333796\platform-tools>

then u check for the ADB server is running or not

D:\sdk-tools-windows-4333796\platform-tools>  adb start-server (enter into cmd prompt just hit enter)

after few second  it will be display i like this

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully

above message say about the server is starting .

simply go to the **Task manager** in the you able to see the **adb.exe** in the process

then Install the Android studios it will work fine.

**Method 2:**

Directly you install the Android Studios .After the completion of installation process.

Go to the terminal inside the Android studios just type the command  adb start-server

After few second  it will be display i like this

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully

[image: Screenshot for command prompt]